# Clementine not playing files with certain characters in the name

Tags: music, locale, clementine, utf-8

Last week I ripped some cds in morituri and rhythmbox. Everything seemed fine except for one cd. After a few tracks I got some weird error while ripping (to FLAC) with morituri, so I ripped the rest of that cd with rhythmbox.

Afterwards Clementine could not play the tracks I ripped from the cd (as wel those ripped with morituri as those ripped with rhythmbox). Clementine acts as if they are not present in my library. With Rhythmbox however, I can perfectly play all the tracks.

I do have the same problem with some mp3 files I got from a friend. I can play them in Rhythmbox, but Clementine acts as if they do not exist.

How do I get it to work normally again? 
I have already tried to reinstall it, deleting the config files, removing the one installed from the repos and installing the latest version from www.clementine-player.org

note: Clementine can perfectly play the other cds I ripped as well as the rest of my music library (mostly in FLAC, with some files in mp3).

I don't know which extra info I can provide, but feel free to ask.

edit: When running clementine in a terminal and then trying to play one of the "problematic" tracks I get the following message:

```
11:36:48.542 INFO  MoodbarLoader:144                Creating moodbar data for "/home/user138784/Music/Stromae/Racine Carrée/01.Ta fête.flac" 
11:36:48.546 ERROR MoodbarPipeline:134              Error processing  QUrl( "file:///home/user138784/Music/Stromae/Racine Carrée/01.Ta fête.flac" )  : "Resource not found." 
11:36:48.546 ERROR MoodbarPipeline:134              Error processing  QUrl( "file:///home/user138784/Music/Stromae/Racine Carrée/01.Ta fête.flac" )  : "Resource not found." 
11:36:48.571 ERROR GstEnginePipeline:563            2 "gstfilesrc.c(1042): gst_file_src_start (): /GstPipeline:pipeline/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin-15/GstFileSrc:source:
No such file "/home/user138784/Music/Stromae/Racine CarrÃ©e/01.Ta fÃªte.flac"" 
11:36:48.572 ERROR GstEnginePipeline:563            2 "gstfilesrc.c(1042): gst_file_src_start (): /GstPipeline:pipeline/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin-15/GstFileSrc:source:
No such file "/home/user138784/Music/Stromae/Racine CarrÃ©e/01.Ta fÃªte.flac"" 
11:36:48.681 WARN  GstEngine:572                    Gstreamer error: "Resource not found." 
11:36:48.684 WARN  unknown                          QTimeLine::start: already running
```

I think the problem might be related to some characters used in the path to the file. For example, the album "Racine Carrée" can not be played, as well as songs from "Goran Bregović".
As I'm using [Beets](https://beets.readthedocs.org/en/v1.3.3/#) to organise my music this path is created automatically. Maybe I can edit my Beets config file to exclude special characters.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10

edit: the `locale` command returns the following output:

```
LANG=en_US
LANGUAGE=en_GB
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME="en_US"
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_PAPER="en_US"
LC_NAME="en_US"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: If you run clementine from a terminal and you try to play those files, do you get any error messages printed out?

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! I feel a bit stupid for not having tried this first.

Comment: user138784 perhaps try converting one of those files to a format like ogg there are programs in the Ubuntu software center that can convert them to ogg like dir2ogg which is command line base and ogg convert which is a gui program

Comment: The problem has noting to do with the codec, but with the path or the file names. The songs can be played when I change the path file names to something without any special characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's bizarre. *"Ta fÃªte"* or *"Ta fête"*, a UTF-8 locale system should be able to open them fine without problems. I just installed Clementine on a fresh copy of Ubuntu 13.10 and test audio files play fine no matter how I altered their pathnames.
I know this sounds stupid, but could you try checking your current locale by typing `locale` in the terminal? I doubt it's the problem but doesn't hurt to check.

Try `locale -a` and see if `en_US.UTF-8` and `en_GB.UTF-8` are available on your system. If they are, you'll want to open your locale configuration files by typing `sudo gedit /etc/default/locale` in terminal, and change everything to using **en_US.UTF-8** (and LANG to **en_GB.UTF-8** if you want UK English instead).

I think LANG alone should be fine, so your locale config file should look like this:

> LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"

After that, reboot your system and try play the files again.

Look at this for more information:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale#Changing_settings_permanently

### If editing /etc/default/locale doesn't work:

First try to manually generate and reconfigure your current locale packages:

```
sudo locale-gen
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Then nstall the language pack so as to make sure the locales do exist in the first place (just to be on the safe side):

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en-base
```

Then, open Language Support from System and try dragging English (United States) to the top, and apply it system-wide. Log off and back in, run `locale` in terminal to see if the changes apply. If it works, great. But it probably won't work if even manually editing the locale file fails, so try `sudo gedit /etc/environment` in terminal, and add this after PATH:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Save and reboot to see if it takes effect. You should see `locale` giving you the correct output this time if it works, otherwise, your system is taking locale settings from some other location instead.

### If it still fails to use UTF-8 for your system locale,

```
sudo gedit etc/bash.bashrc
```

Add in this to the last line (be careful not to edit anything else):

```
# Forcing locale to en_US.UTF-8
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Save and reboot.

Comment: Can you comment now?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. I need just 9 more reputation but I guess I'll get them in time. Thanks for the help.

Comment: well good luck getting those nine points

Comment: I added the output of `locale`. I indeed had some locale-related problems after doing a clean install of 13.10 (to solve some problems I had after upgrading to 13.10 from 13.04, but it didn't change anything)

Comment: My locale file only contains `LANG="en_GB.UTF-8" `

Comment: I'm using vanilla ubuntu 13.10 with unity, so I suppose that's a no.

Comment: Alright, that rules out GDM's behavior of overwriting your locale settings then. It's still quite apparent the fault lies in your system locale, as for some reason it's not reading your locale config. Can you try `cat /etc/environment | grep LANG` and see what it outputs?

Comment: I don't get any output...

Comment: @user138784 Damn, this is puzzling. Anyway, I've updated and added in two other methods. Try them in order and see if it helps. I'm out of ideas as well if they don't work. Deleted my previous comments as it was getting a little too long.

Answer (score 3):

As I tought, the problem is indeed caused by special characters in the file name or the path. Changing this will solves the problem.

A better solution would of course be to make clementine read the special characters correctly, but I haven't found out how to do this yet, maybe it's a bug.

edit:
I might be [this bug](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/issues/2106).

edit2:
On second tought, I think it isn't, as Ubuntu uses UFT-8 (if I'm not mistaking, I have little knowledge about this stuff)

Answer (score 0):

It seems Clementine makes URIs out of the filenames. Spaces arent allowed in URI's, even using UTF-8. The need to be escaped by `%20`. Other special chars should also be escaped

You could try to replace the Spaces in the filenames with underscores, hyphens etc. and the special chars like `é` or `ê` by the default latin chars, e.g. `e`.

If you do that to the file- and foldernames, this won't affect how the stuff is shown in Clementine - this is read from the ID3 tags, which allow such characters. So rename that stuff and relaod your Clementine library. That should fix it.

To explain the UTF-8 vs. ASCII stuff:

Ubuntu uses UTF-8 as default (at least as far as I know), but URIs use ASCII only, so every Unicode char like `é`, which is twice as big as ASCII, is interpreted as two ASCII chars: `Ã©`

Comment: Spaces in file names aren't a problem, special characters are. But the strange thing is: it used to work on ubuntu 13.04 as far as I know. (I don't know when the problems exactly started, but I suppose it was after I upgraded to 13.10)

Comment: Then just replace the special chars...